# DecimalSeparator in SysUtils and System.SysUtils

Tags: delphi, components, vcl

I need to find DecimalSeparator var SysUtils Delphi 7, in Delphi XE6 i tried to find in System.SysUtils, but without success. Someone can tell me where to find her in Delphi XE6?

In Delphi 7 it is located in SysUtils.pas unit, in line 618:

```
var 
   CurrencyString: string; 
   CurrencyFormat: Byte; 
   NegCurrFormat: Byte; 
   ThousandSeparator: Char; 
   DecimalSeparator: Char;
```

I need this variable to convert a component of Delphi 7 to XE6

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.FormatSettings

Answer (score 27, accepted):

My bad, first I needed to call `FormatSettings`, and then I can use in `DecimalSeparator` in Delphi XE6,

```
FormatSettings.DecimalSeparator
```

Comment: The global formatting variables were deprecated in XE and were finally [removed in XE6](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Global_Variables).

Comment: A global variable FormatSettings exists, along with all the problems that you can expect from a global variable. Keep this as a rule of thumb: as soon as you *write* to `FormatSettings`, you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: @Wouter van Nifterick. I'm agree that formatSetting is not the best state of art. Then what is your solution ? what is the best State of Art to not use FormatSetting ?

Comment: @ffert2907: do not use the global variable, but populate a local instance of TFormatSettings, and pass that on explicitly. The global one should've never been created by Borland in the first place, because any function can change it at any time.. 

If you _change_ it, who know what you're affecting, or if you _use_ it, who knows that messed with it. So just avoid it whenever you can...

Answer (score 7):

```
procedure ConfigureBrazilRegion;
var
  FormatBr: TFormatSettings;
begin
  // Create new setting and configure for the brazillian format
  FormatBr                     := TFormatSettings.Create;
  FormatBr.DecimalSeparator    := ',';
  FormatBr.ThousandSeparator   := '.';
  FormatBr.CurrencyDecimals    := 2;
  FormatBr.DateSeparator       := '/';
  FormatBr.ShortDateFormat     := 'dd/mm/yyyy';
  FormatBr.LongDateFormat      := 'dd/mm/yyyy';
  FormatBr.TimeSeparator       := ':';
  FormatBr.TimeAMString        := 'AM';
  FormatBr.TimePMString        := 'PM';
  FormatBr.ShortTimeFormat     := 'hh:nn';
  FormatBr.LongTimeFormat      := 'hh:nn:ss';
  FormatBr.CurrencyString      := 'R$';

  // Assign the App region settings to the newly created format
  System.SysUtils.FormatSettings := WFormatBr;
end;
```

Comment: @user30478 the description is the question, just read it first and comment if you still have any doubts.

Comment: Thanks. This is a code from kazip 2.0 demo. It uses this separator like -
 TS   := SysUtils.ThousandSeparator;
   Try
      SysUtils.ThousandSeparator := ' ';
... finally.. 
      SysUtils.ThousandSeparator := TS; end;
don't know how to make this D7 code work for DXE5.

Comment: Hey @user30478, look at the code again. Hope you understand with comments. This code works with DXE5.